# Does not work with "type": "module" in "package.json"

Tags: node.js, express, npm, webpack

i run npm start

get the error

```
(node:1079) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
/Users/sangkuoh/Desktop/Udacity_FEND_TravelApp-master/src/server/server.js:61
export default { app };
^^^^^^
```

why this don't work? :)

Comment: Add more information about your situation. What are you trying to achieve, what npm start looks like in your package.json. What are the logs in your terminal, not just the last few lines.

Comment: This also doesn't work for me. Node seems to completely ignore the "type": "module" in package.json. Background: I'm trying to run a CoffeeScript file using the coffee executable, but the error message is clearly coming from nodejs. For more background, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67759943/using-es6-modules-in-coffeescript

Answer (score -1):

Add

```
"type": "module"
```

in your **package.json**