# Using es6 modules in coffeescript

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

es6 modules are supposed to work in coffeescript (see https://coffeescript.org/#modules), but even with an extremely simple project, it doesn't work for me. I:

1. Created a new directory
2. Ran 'npm init -y' in it
3. Added the key "type": "module" in my package.json
4. Created 2 files: index.coffee and utils.coffee

   import {myprint} from 'utils.coffee'
   myprint("Hello, World!")

   export myprint = (str) ->
      console.log(str)

when I try to execute index.coffee (via 'coffee index.coffee' - I've tried both git's bash shell - on Windows and PowerShell), I get the following error message:

(node:1856) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.

and later:

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Answer (score 2):

This is all correct as far as I understand. Coffeescript transpiles the import/export statements correctly, but does not provide an environment to run them.

From the [documentation](https://coffeescript.org/#modules):

> Note that the CoffeeScript compiler does not resolve modules; writing an import or export statement in CoffeeScript will produce an import or export statement in the resulting output. It is your responsibility to transpile this ES2015 syntax into code that will work in your target runtimes.

You won't be able to run this code via either `coffee` or `node --require coffeescript/register`. I believe you will have to transpile your code and run the resulting JS via `node`

Comment: I understand that the error is actually coming from node, not coffee. However, transpiling should not be necessary since I've got node set up to recognize es6 modules natively. I thought that someone that uses coffeescript this way might know the answer, but it will probably take someone who knows node intimately to explain why this doesn't work when it should. That's why I added the keyword "node.js" to this question.

Comment: Node knows about esm, but it doesn't know what to do with a coffeescript file when loaded as an esm. You need something to transpile each coffee file loaded via `import` on the fly. There is a set of coffeescript loaders here which may be what you need: https://github.com/GeoffreyBooth/node-loaders/tree/master/coffeescript-loader

Comment: The problem, if I understand you correctly, is that when running coffee on my main file, it finds "import {X} from 'Y.coffee', which is just copies to the output JavaScript (only appending a semicolon), but when node tries to execute that, it doesn't know how to import a coffee module. Makes sense.

Comment: But: 1) that doesn't explain why node complains that I'm using 'import' outside of a module when I've got "type": "module" in my package.json - unless the .coffee extension causes it to ignore that setting (but then it should just complain that it doesn't understand .coffee files), and 2) the node-loaders that you recommend has very minimal documentation - not even how to use it. I'll try to figure it out, but I think that will take me some time.

Comment: I usually interpret the word "transpile" to just mean changing an es6 JavaScript file to a pre-es6 JavaScript file. But what's needed here is to arrange to convert a coffeescript file to a JavaScript file (which can be es6 since node can handle that now). I'm guessing that's what the node-loaders thing does, but unfortunately, I don't know how to use it. I'll try googling ;-)